# How to display a link's content as text within the element

Tags: html

How can I display a link's target as text using HTML?

Example:

```
<a href="file:///C:\Users\jy\Documents\data.xlsx">file:///C:\Users\jy\Documents\data.xlsx</a>
```

Specifically, I want the text to reflect the value of the data of a cell in an Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx file) that my link points to.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting an element's attribute into the element as text is actually possible  entirely with CSS.

The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors allow you to insert content into the element and you can specify the content to be an attribute of that element with `attr()`. Like so:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/"></a>
```

```
a:after {
  content: attr(href);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JackHasaKeyboard/7osos9du/

Comment: You want to grab the value in a cell within an Excel file and insert it into the link's text? That's a question specific to Excel and how to parse .xlsx files, afraid I can't help with that.

Comment: Example  this is the hyperlink text  _360__ and the number 360 is actually the value in the link file. If i change the number in the file, link text will change automatically.   
< a href ="file:///C:\Users\jy\Documents\data.xlsx">360</a>

Comment: Yeah, half of that question regards Excel and how to parse its files which I can't answer. The other half regards grabbing text value from a link and inserting it in the element which I'm not sure about but I'd start off by figuring out how to grab data from Excel spreadsheets with a scraper or something.